# Automatically fill From: field and add today's date in email's body, with Gmail Canned Responses

Tags: gmail, gmail-canned-response

Every month I need to send an email to the water company, containing various info. Since the email has always the same structure, I created a template with Gmail Canned Responses.

However, the water company lives in the Mesozoic and doesn't know how to automatically read the date field of an email. Thus I have to include the date *explicitly* inside the message body. For example, this is the template I'm using:

```
Owner: blablabla
Address: blablabla
OwnerID: iureqiouq
Date: **here goes today's date**
Reading:
```

Is there a way to get Gmail to automatically insert the current date in the mail body?

Also, it looks like I cannot save a Canned Response with a predefined From: field, so I need to include the water company email address each time. It's not a big deal thanks to Gmail From: field autocompletion, but still I wonder if I could avoid this step.

Basically, I would like to be able to load the Canned Response, include the only info which Gmail can't find by itself (the water consumption reading), click "Send", and be done with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. Canned responses are static text.

You'll need to look at a different tool for this. Something like [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) might be useful.